# Sending Messages Back to the Template After Processing?

Tags: functions, actions, page-template, forms

Is there an "offical" way to send a message back to the template after processing a form using `add_action('admin_post')` or similar for client-side feedback ?

I was thinking of using the `$_SESSION` but wasn't sure if there was a preferably way of doing this.

Comment: What does it mean to "send a message back to the template"?

Comment: sending feedback from the process to the user ... like form errors / success, etc.

Comment: Have you thought about [`admin_notices`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) hook? `$_SESSION` is also great for this to store a log message and destroy upon show, and you can take advantage of WP admin notices classes ( e.g `<div class="updated notice is-dismissible"><p>Changes saved successfully.</p></div>` )

Comment: Why not use Ajax?  jQuery has a nice Ajax form submit wrapper...works great for this sort of thing.